# Which is the easiest way for Scrapy scrapers to respect Crawl-Delay in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt, scrapy

Is there a setting  that I can toggle or `DownloaderMiddleware` which I can use that will enforce the Crawl-Delay setting of robots.txt? If not, how do I implement rate limiting within a scraper?

Comment: See my answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378726/is-it-possible-to-access-the-reactor-from-a-scrapy-spider/8388289#8388289

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request ([#892](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/892)) to support this in Scrapy, but it is not currently implemented.

However, [#892](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/892) includes a link to a code fragment that you could use as a starting point to create your own implementation.

If you do, and you are up to the task, consider sending a pull request to Scrapy to integrate your changes.

Answer (score -5):

Spider can or cannot respect the crawl delay in the robots.txt, it's not mandatory to parse the robots.txt for bots!

You can use a firewall who will ban an ip which is crawling aggressively in your website.

Do you know which bots cause you trouble? Google Bot or other big search engine use bots which try to not overflow your server.