# Is it possible to access the reactor from a Scrapy spider?

Tags: scrapy

I'm looking at ways of implementing a crawl delays inside of Scrapy spiders. I was wondering if it is possible to do access the reactor's [`callLater`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.base.ReactorBase.html#callLater) method from within a spider? That would enable a page to be parsed after *n* seconds quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a delay with ease actually by setting the DOWNLOAD_DELAY in the settings file.

> DOWNLOAD_DELAY
>
> Default: 0
>
> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before
>   downloading consecutive pages from the same spider. This can be used
>   to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.
>   Decimal numbers are supported. Example:
>
> DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25    # 250 ms of delay This setting is also
>   affected by the RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting (which is enabled by
>   default). By default, Scrapy doesn’t wait a fixed amount of time
>   between requests, but uses a random interval between 0.5 and 1.5 *
>   DOWNLOAD_DELAY.
>
> You can also change this setting per spider.

See also [Scrapy's Docs - DOWNLOAD_DELAY](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std%3asetting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY)

Comment: Not quite an answer to the question, but does skip it and solve the underlying problem.